# HP Envy-15 Notebook running Ubuntu 15.10 having discharge related issues

Tags: battery

I currently possess a HP Envy-15 notebook with Ubuntu 15.10 Velvet Currently Dual Booting with Windows 8.1

When the battery have a charge of 100% and I turn off the Laptop from Ubuntu the next time I turn on my notebook the battery charge is decreased of approximately 20% in about 12 hours.

If I turn off my notebook from Windows the battery charge remains at 100%. Any explanation will be welcome

Comment: How do you turn off the laptop?

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like Ubuntu can't properly turn off your hard drive or CPU/GPU. This can be related to drivers, the kernel, or the installation itself.

If you're using the proprietary Nividia/AMD drivers try turning them off. If you're using the open source Xorg drivers, try installation the proprietary drivers.

Otherwise, I've seen some shut off problems which relate to BIOS security ie. secureboot. By default, Windows 8.1 requires secureboot. While Linux does support this functionality, I try to avoid it at all costs. Basically, your Ubuntu can't access the hardware properly because your BIOS is blocking it.

What we need to know is your dual boot set up. Did you install Ubuntu in a loop mounted volume through the installer file from Ubuntu's website? Or did you use a bootable USB and install it directly into the BIOS?

Comment: I have a  Nvidia card and I use the proprietaty drivers. I tried to use open source Xorg drivers but I had some troubles.
Secureboot is disabled in my BIOS.
I have installed Ubuntu 15.04 directly with DVD and  I subsequently made the upgrade to Ubuntu 15.10. I had the same problem with Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: Ahh.When you make an Ubuntu live USB, remove the folder in the drive called "EFI." That'll force Ubuntu into BIOS boot

Comment: I'm sorry but I did not understand very well, can you explain better?